# Best practice to build a pergola type structure

Tags: patio, pavers, pergola

Having patio pavers laid,
I want to build a pergola like structure for my home in the Northeast.

Something like this:

[image]

Questions about best practice:

1. Should I use tubular forms outside the patio?
2. Can I lay/secure directly on the (expensive) pavers?
3. 4x4 treated lumber ok?

Here is how I saw a display model done:

[image]

Comment: Please ask just one question at a time. Each of those could be a separate post as they're not related other than in that they pertain to your overall project.

Comment: @isherwood - Technically speaking. The correct answer of YES to question #1 is directly related to the correct answer of NO to question #2.

Comment: If the question is whether to use footings outside or post bases inside the patio area, that's one question and should be made more clear. As its written, question #1 appears to be about footing _type_, not importance. At any rate, scope is too broad.